# VBA Word - setting last line of the last page as a range (or other means if necessary)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to set the last line of the last page in a word document as a range (or any other means if necessary)?

I can get to the Last page and the last line using `Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory` but I cant set that line as a range

If it isnt possible to set the line using range you can use any other method if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the entire line from the end of the document and a Range from that selection:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory 
Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdLine, Count:=-1
Set rng = Selection.Range
```

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer as it answers perfectly what I asked, I just asked the wrong question, still this will likely be useful for me later on. Thanks